# Google App Make: Unable to choose Cloud SQL option for deployment

Tags: google-app-maker

I wish to run an App Maker application as a specific user and have created an account specifically for deploying with "run as the developer".

Using my normal account I have no issues deploying but when using the new account I do not get any options presented for Cloud SQL.  As this user is not able to choose either option then it is impossible to deploy the app.

The following has been checked already

1. The new user has the same application rights as my normal user within the G-Suite admin console.
2. The new user has editor rights to the App Maker project (is owner).
3. The new user has owner rights to the GCP project that hosts the default Cloud SQL instance.
4. The default Cloud SQL instance is the same for both users.

Is there anything I am missing that could cause this behaviour?